# Language/Code page issue between a Windows Application and a Windows Service

Tags: service, localization

I have a Windows application and a Windows Service that both make calls to a common DLL. This common DLL spawns a process which generates my output. When run on a non-US Windows OS (zh-TW in this case) the Windows Application generates output as expected. When run as a Windows Service the output appears to be passed through a US code page as the output contains “boxes” used for non-mapped characters. This issue occurs even when the Service has a Log On As the same User that was used to run the Windows Application. There is something different in the initial environment in which the process is being launched as an application vs. service. Any information on what this difference is, and how to correct it, would be greatly appreciated.